# C# Minio PutBucket Request: A WebException with status NameResolutionFailure was thrown

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, object-storage, minio

I'm working on an Amazon s3 Compatible Object Storage solution (Minio).

I have an Minio server on e.g 192.168.235.143:9000

I have tried to get List of buckets on C# version of Amazon s3 Api.
Everything works fine.

When I try to Put a Bucket into this server e.g `test1`, Visual studio throws this request into an Exception:

```
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: 
'A WebException with status NameResolutionFailure was thrown.'

WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'test1.192.168.235.143'
```

here is my code:

```
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
config.ServiceURL = "192.168.235.143:9000";
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(AccessKey, SecretKey, config);
PutBucketRequest request = new PutBucketRequest();
request.BucketName = "test1";
// this Line will throws above exception :
client.PutBucket(request);
```

but `ListBuckets` works for make me confused:

```
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(AccessKey, SecretKey, config);
var response = client.ListBuckets();
foreach (S3Bucket b in response.Buckets)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}\t{1}", b.BucketName, b.CreationDate));
}
```

What i have tested to check this Exception's cause:

1. I have Installed it on a Virtual machine and a local Version for doubly check this issue but it still persists.
2. I Even Changed Minio port to the `port #80`
3. I Even used "play.min.io" but has no difference

I need to use a known interface so we be able to port into another Object Storage Platform e.g Ceph, ....

I have no Idea to get it resolved yet.

Please Help me to find my mistake or a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i have found a sample working code, Thanks to Minio GitHub Community:

```
using Amazon.S3;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon;

class Program
{
     private const string accessKey = "PLACE YOUR ACCESS KEY HERE";
     private const string secretKey = "PLACE YOUR SECRET KEY HERE"; // do not store secret key hardcoded in your production source code!

     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         Task.Run(MainAsync).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
     }

     private static async Task MainAsync()
     {
         var config = new AmazonS3Config
         {
             RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1, // MUST set this before setting ServiceURL and it should match the `MINIO_REGION` enviroment variable.
             ServiceURL = "http://localhost:9000", // replace http://localhost:9000 with URL of your MinIO server
             ForcePathStyle = true // MUST be true to work correctly with MinIO server
         };
         var amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, config); 

         // uncomment the following line if you like to troubleshoot communication with S3 storage and implement private void OnAmazonS3Exception(object sender, Amazon.Runtime.ExceptionEventArgs e)
         // amazonS3Client.ExceptionEvent += OnAmazonS3Exception;

         var listBucketResponse = await amazonS3Client.ListBucketsAsync();

         foreach (var bucket in listBucketResponse.Buckets)
         {
             Console.Out.WriteLine("bucket '" + bucket.BucketName + "' created at " + bucket.CreationDate);
         }
         if (listBucketResponse.Buckets.Count > 0)
         {
             var bucketName = listBucketResponse.Buckets[0].BucketName;

             var listObjectsResponse = await amazonS3Client.ListObjectsAsync(bucketName);

             foreach (var obj in listObjectsResponse.S3Objects)
             {
                 Console.Out.WriteLine("key = '" + obj.Key + "' | size = " + obj.Size + " | tags = '" + obj.ETag + "' | modified = " + obj.LastModified);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```